# Can't view sqlite db datas in iPad mini

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode5

I developed a iOS Universal app using Sqlite db. I can access the app and it's db in the simulator but when I run the app in the device(iPad mini) it not displays the datas stored in the db. Kindly advice me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete app from ipad and then run

Comment: @Indrajeet I did it many times but still facing the same..

Comment: add your db creation source code for reference.